# NPM package excel-as-json fires callback early

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using excel-as-json NPM package to convert an excel file to json (https://www.npmjs.com/package/excel-as-json).

As per the documentation the last parameter is the callback function. So, I wrote this:

```
convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;


function fixJson(fileName){

    var jsonfile = require('jsonfile');
    var file = fileName;

    jsonfile.readFile(file, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
            console.log(err);
        }
    })



}

convertExcel('test.xlsx', 'test.json', {sheet:"1"}, fixJson('test.json'));
```

But when I run this file through node, the callback function fixJson() fires before the conversion completes. Due to this I get an error "Unexpected end of JSON input". When I look at the JSON file, it contains the data.

Am I doing something wrong here? or there is a problem with the callback function?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docs says:

```
convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;
convertExcel(src, dst, options, callback);

//callback(err, data): callback for completion notification
```

The callbacks in JS are executed at a later point in time, so you just pass the function reference:

```
convertExcel = require('excel-as-json').processFile;

function fixJson(error, file_data){
    // 'file_data' will contain the converted data, or 'error' will contain the error occured
}

convertExcel('test.xlsx', 'test.json', {sheet:"1"}, fixJson);
```

Comment: Ah yes. Totally missed it. Thanks. Ok, so supposed I need to manipulate and save file_data as a json file, how can I pass the filename? Should I pass it as a command line parameter and then read process.argv inside the callback function? Or do you suggest another method?

Comment: `convertExcel(src, dst, options, callback)`: doesnt this line basically take the xlsx file at `src` and save it as a json to `dst` ?! Try it without the callback `convertExcel(src, dst, {sheet:"1"})`

Comment: Yes it does that. I need to actually take the json data, covert all the "\n" to "<br/>" tags and save it back to the file. But the file name is not hardcoded. It needs to be passed dynamically.

Comment: Quite a long shot, this. But, to get the filename inside `fixJson`, try this: `fixJson.caller.arguments`. You might be able to get `dst` from that, and then use `fs` or something to save the modified json

Comment: No worries. I will figure out that part :). Thanks.